# linker option -Bsymbolic

Tags: c++, linux, linker, new-operator, elf

I replace `operator new` and `operator delete` inside shared library.
I want that when I do `dlopen` on this shared library replaced versions of `operator new` and `operator delete` from shared library were used(not versions from the binary which runs `dlopen()`).
To achieve this I pass -Bsymbolic option to the linker and it seems doesn't working.

Here is MWE:

main.cpp

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <iostream>

#include "library.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "going call library function" << std::endl;

    using func_t = decltype(library_function);
    auto handle = dlopen("./libshared.so", RTLD_NOW);
    auto fnc = reinterpret_cast<func_t*>(dlsym(handle, "library_function"));
    fnc();
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

library.h

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

extern "C" void library_function();

#endif // LIBRARY_H
```

library.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern "C" void library_function()
{
    std::string str;

    str.resize(10);

    std::cout << "inside library function: " << str.size() << std::endl;
}
```

new.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

void* operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "operator new from shared library" << std::endl;

    void* ptr = malloc(size);

    if(!ptr) throw std::bad_alloc();

    return ptr;
}

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "operator new from shared library" << std::endl;

    return malloc(size);
}

void* operator new[](std::size_t size)
{
    return ::operator new(size);
}

void* operator new[](std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow) noexcept
{
    return ::operator new(size, nothrow);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "operator delete from shared library" << std::endl;

    return free(ptr);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept
{
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    return ::operator delete(ptr);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    return ::operator delete(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept
{
    return ::operator delete(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept
{
    return ::operator delete(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    return ::operator delete(ptr);
}

void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    return ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    c++ -std=c++14 -g2 -O0 -shared -fPIC -o libshared.so library.cpp new.cpp -Wl,-Bsymbolic

    c++ -std=c++14 -g2 -O0 main.cpp -o main -ldl
```

Output from main:

```
$ ./main 
going call library function
inside library function: 10
```

Expected output: output contains  "operator new from shared library" , "operator delete from shared library" .

And the second question - how the same behavior can be achieved when I explicitly link with this library(-lshared for main.cpp).

**Update**:

It seems that actually linker make changes w/ or w/o `-Bsymbolic`.
Considering `diff` from `readelf -r` on shared libraries w/ and w/o `-Bsymbolic`:

```
-Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0xeb0 contains 20 entries:
+Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0xeb0 contains 15 entries:
   Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
-000000202018  002700000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 00000000000014b7 operator new(unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) + 0
-000000202020  000300000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_s@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
-000000202028  003000000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 000000000000142c operator new(unsigned long) + 0
-000000202030  000600000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 std::ios_base::Init::Init@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
-000000202038  000700000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
-000000202040  003100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 000000000000153f operator delete(void*) + 0
-000000202048  000800000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __cxa_atexit@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
-000000202050  000b00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZStlsISt11char_traits@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
-000000202058  000c00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_s@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
-000000202060  000d00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 free@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
-000000202068  000f00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_s@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
-000000202070  002e00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 00000000000016b8 std::exception::exception() + 0
-000000202078  001200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
-000000202080  002f00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 00000000000016d6 std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc() + 0
-000000202088  001500000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4 + 0
-000000202090  001600000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __cxa_allocate_excepti@CXXABI_1.3 + 0
-000000202098  001700000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
-0000002020a0  001800000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __cxa_throw@CXXABI_1.3 + 0
-0000002020a8  001900000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
-0000002020b0  001c00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _Unwind_Resume@GCC_3.0 + 0
+000000202018  000300000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_s@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
+000000202020  000600000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 std::ios_base::Init::Init@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
+000000202028  000700000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
+000000202030  000800000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __cxa_atexit@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
+000000202038  000b00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZStlsISt11char_traits@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
+000000202040  000c00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_s@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
+000000202048  000d00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 free@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
+000000202050  000f00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_s@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
+000000202058  001200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
+000000202060  001500000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4 + 0
+000000202068  001600000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __cxa_allocate_excepti@CXXABI_1.3 + 0
+000000202070  001700000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_@GLIBCXX_3.4.21 + 0
+000000202078  001800000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __cxa_throw@CXXABI_1.3 + 0
+000000202080  001900000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))@GLIBCXX_3.4 + 0
+000000202088  001c00000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 _Unwind_Resume@GCC_3.0 + 0
```

It seems that operator new/operator delete are not marked relocatable while building with -Bsymbolic - therefore internal version must be used?

**Update:**
Indeed I see difference in calling operator new:

w/o -Bsymbolic call goes through PLT and GOT:

```
   0x000000000000109c <+28>:    callq  0xed0 <_Znam@plt>
```

w/ -Bsymbolic call doesn't go through PLT and GOT:

```
   0x0000000000000f7c <+28>:    callq  0x110a <operator new[](unsigned long)>
```

**Update:**

Actually it seems that right version of operator new/operator delete is called. Step instructions in GDB shows it. The problem is that operator<< to cout stream from shared library is not working.

**Update:**

It seems that problem is caused by the fact that when I call resize on std::string - the symbol is used from the binary and not from the library.  Inside std::string resize function from the binary the call to operator new is routed to its local definition - that's why I don't see call of replaced operator new/operator delete.
It starts working when I directly use operator new/operator delete from library.

**Update:**

Yes, the problem disappear when statically linking with `libstdc++`(`libc++`).

Comment: So, you have a C++ program that's been using one set of `operator new` and `operator delete` functions (because it has been running before you get to call `dlopen()`).  Then you want to load your shared library via `dlopen()` and have its versions of the memory management take over for all the existing memory plus any future memory.  How quickly can you say "crash!"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, assume that I fully understand the problem and I know what I'm doing. The actual answer is more tricky -  all operator new/operator delete from shared library will be routed to operator new/operator delete from the binary that made dlopen, but through specific interface(callgate) between binary and shared library.

Comment: OK; on your own head be it.  But I'm puzzled that you need to ask this question if you meet those requirements.  I've no clue and wouldn't risk it, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided example actually works.
The problem is that verification scenario for problem(allocation memory through calling std::string resize method) is bad. Because call to resize method is dynamically routed by PLT/GOT to version from the binary. And std::string resize method in binary calls its own `operator new`/`operator delete` (not versions from the shared library).
In order to workaround this - we can statically compile with libstdc++(`-static-libstdc++`).